# Why is there no transaction in my thread? JPA JTS/JTA Glassfish 4

Tags: java, web-services, jpa, glassfish, jta

I'm writing a small EJB3 application deployed on glassfish 4 and using the derbyDB that comes with glassfish.

To make testing easy I have declared one of my EJBs as @Webservice so I can trigger a method with the testers provided by glassfish. So far so good.

The callstack is like this:
**DailyReportingJob**( @Stateless and @WebService, EntryPoint for my test)
**-->**  **VerfahrensArchivService** (@Stateless and @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRES_NEW) )

my persistence.xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="zvagent">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/zvagentdb</jta-data-source>
        <class>de.kevinfleischer.zvagent.verfahren.Verfahren</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.deploy-on-startup" value="true"/>
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I've configured a connection pool in glassfish of ressource type javax.sql.DataSource and a jdbc ressource with the name jdbc/zvagentdb that points to this pool.

When I trigger the webservice I see my app working. But when I try to call the VerfahrensArchivService - which should store data to the DB - the following warning shows up. In the webinterface of the webservice tester I see further an InvocationTargetException, telling me the call to "doPost" failed.

```
WARNING: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction is not active in the current thread.
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2016)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy455.storeAndUpdateVerfahren(Unknown Source)
at de.kevinfleischer.zvagent.archiv.__EJB31_Generated__VerfahrensArchivService__Intf____Bean__.storeAndUpdateVerfahren(Unknown Source)
at de.kevinfleischer.zvagent.job.DailyReportingJob.executeJob(DailyReportingJob.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

The DB is empty afterwards. No Data was stored.

(I have JUnit tests, that work completely local without appserver, that show, that the code would store data. So its a transaction problem, not a problem in the business code.)

Comment: If somebody could provide me a sampel JEE5 maven project which runs on glassfish 4 and uses the derbyDB this would be awesome. Like a code snippet. Or maybe you could point out a tutorial that sets one up.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found that the configuration was no problem. The packaging was rubbish and the errors I got only follow up errors.